# In Rails, pagy style is not customizable

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bulma, pagy

I am using Rails, Bulma css framework, and pagy gem.

```rb
<nav class="pagination">
<span class="" style=" margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; font-weight:700;" > 
<%== pagy_prev_link(@pagy, '‹ Previous', ' id="" class="pagination-link " style=""  ') if @pagy.pages > 1 %>
</span>

<span class="" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; font-weight:700; ">
<%== pagy_next_link(@pagy, 'Next ›', 'id="" style="" class="pagination-link  " ') if @pagy.pages > 1 %>
</span>
</nav>
```

The problem is that no matter what I try, I can't customize the look of the next and prev buttons. Right now the buttons show as bold-font Next and Prev, with Next in default blue, as there are more than 1 pages. I want to turn it into another color and also make it look like button with Bulma. I've tried inputting "pagination-link" to span; to controller where the pagy is; getting rid of span; didn't work.

What can I do? I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can custom the bulma pagy nav by create `app/views/pagy/_bulma_nav.html.erb` with content:

```
<style>
  .custom_color_green {
    color: green !important;
    background-color: yellow !important;
  }
</style>
<%#
  This template is i18n-ready: if you don't use i18n, then you can replace the pagy_t
  calls with the actual strings ("&lsaquo; Prev", "Next &rsaquo;", "&hellip;").

  The link variable is set to a proc that returns the link tag.
  Usage: link.call( page_number [, text [, extra_attributes_string ]])
-%>
<% link = pagy_link_proc(pagy) -%>
<%#                            -%><nav class="pagy-bulma-nav pagination is-centered" role="navigation" aria-label="pagination">
<% if pagy.prev                -%>  <%== link.call(pagy.prev, pagy_t('pagy.nav.prev'), 'class="pagination-previous" aria-label="previous page"') %>
<% else                        -%>  <a class="pagination-previous custom_color_green" disabled><%== pagy_t('pagy.nav.prev') %></a>
<% end                         -%>
<% if pagy.next                -%>  <%== link.call(pagy.next, pagy_t('pagy.nav.next'), 'class="pagination-next has-text-danger has-background-success" aria-label="next page"') %>
<% else                        -%>  <a class="pagination-next" disabled><%== pagy_t('pagy.nav.next') %></a>
<% end                         -%>
<%#                            -%>  <ul class="pagination-list">
<% pagy.series.each do |item| # series example: [1, :gap, 7, 8, "9", 10, 11, :gap, 36] -%>
<%   if    item.is_a?(Integer) -%>    <li><%== link.call item, item, %(class="pagination-link" aria-label="goto page #{item}") %></li>
<%   elsif item.is_a?(String)  -%>    <li><%== link.call item, item, %(class="pagination-link is-current" aria-label="page #{item}" aria-current="page") %></li>
<%   elsif item == :gap        -%>    <li><span class="pagination-ellipsis"><%== pagy_t('pagy.nav.gap') %></span></li>
<%   end                       -%>
<% end                         -%>
<%#                            -%>  </ul>
<%#                            -%></nav>
```

Then include it in view, example file `app/views/pages/home.html.erb`:

```
Welcome to project railstrace !
<% @records.each do |r| %>
  <p>Name: <%= r.name %> Description: <%= r.description %> </p>
<% end %>
<%== render partial: 'pagy/bulma_nav', locals: {pagy: @pagy} %>
```

And simple controller such as `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  include Pagy::Backend

  def home
    Pagy::VARS[:max_items] = 10 # Set the value you want!
    @pagy, @records = pagy(Trip.all)
  end
end
```

You will get this successful result:
[image]